# Search Bar IOS 8 - Showing Two Search Bars

Tags: ios, xcode, uisearchbar

Am Using UISearchController IOS  8, Used ResultUpDating Delegate

Code Given Below

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.products = [Product allProducts];

    // Create a mutable array to contain products for the search results table.
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.products count]];

    // The table view controller is in a nav controller, and so the containing nav controller is the 'search results controller'
    UINavigationController *searchResultsController = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TableSearchResultsNavController"];

    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;

    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;

#if ENABLE_SCOPE_BUTTONS

    NSMutableArray *scopeButtonTitles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [scopeButtonTitles addObject:NSLocalizedString(@"All", @"Search display controller All button.")];

    for (NSString *deviceType in [Product deviceTypeNames]) {
        NSString *displayName = [Product displayNameForType:deviceType];
        [scopeButtonTitles addObject:displayName];
    }

    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = scopeButtonTitles;
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

#endif

    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;

}
```

Delegate Methods Are

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController{
    // Set searchString equal to what's typed into the searchbar
    NSString *searchString = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
    //NSLog(@"o");

    [self fetchByPatientName:searchString];



}
- (void)fetchByPatientName:(NSString *)patientName
{

//Code TO Fetch

// Code To Update Table

}
```

My Stroy Board
[[image]][1

Aftr Running Am Getting Two SearchBars , Am Seeking How to Slove It

Your Help Kindly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the following should resolve it

```
 self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
```